# Confusion regarding Young's double slit experiment in different media

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, waves, double-slit-experiment, interference

### The Problem

> Consider the given arrangement:
>
> [image]
>
> Point $P$ is equidistant from $S_1$ and $S_2$ .The glass slab in air has refractive index $\mu_{2}$, and the one in water($\mu_{1}$) has refractive index $\mu_{3}$. We need to find the relation between $\mu_{2}$ and $\mu_{3}$ such that $P$ is the central maxima. Both glass slabs have thickness $t$.

### Approach

If a glass slab is placed in the path of one of the slits, the path length difference is:
$$t\left[\dfrac{\mu_{glass}}{\mu_{medium}}-1\right]$$
The Condition for Point $P$ to be the central maxima is that there shouldn't be any optical path difference. I believe the optical path difference is
$$\left[\mu_{air}t\left[\dfrac{\mu_{2}}{\mu_{air}}-1\right]\right] - \left[\mu_{water}t\left[\dfrac{\mu_{3}}{\mu_{water}}-1\right] \right]=0$$

Thus, the answer should be $\mu_{2}+\mu_{1}-1 = \mu_{3}$. However, the correct answer is $\mu_{3}=\mu_{1}*\mu_{2}$: Which upon reverse engineering, we will get from the equation:
$$t\left[\dfrac{\mu_{2}}{\mu_{air}}-1\right] - t\left[\dfrac{\mu_{3}}{\mu_{water}}-1\right]=0$$
**So why exactly is the above equation true?** It seems to me that this equation simply equates the path difference(s) without accounting for the fact that light goes through different media.

I guess to remove all confusion one has to write the wave equation. But, since the waves travel through different media, I don't quite know how to do that.

Comment: Why do you think that the two waves have gone through different media?

Comment: Related: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/121173/2021/3/23